# Creating a dynamic xlsx with the write_xlsx gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to export a part of my db for the user as a .xlsx

I managed to create a static file and let the user download it, but that's not really the point.

The user should select the filter he wants and as a result the file should be created and downloaded directly through the browser.

my code looks something like this:

controller

```
def download_pdf
  send_data generate_pdf,
            type: "application/xlsx"
end

private

def generate_pdf
  workbook = WriteXLSX.new('export.xlsx')

  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet

  worksheet.write(0, 0, 'status')
  worksheet.write(0, 1, 'date')
  worksheet.write(0, 2, 'customer')

  workbook
end
```

the result would be a file and the content is just the name of the object

```
#<WriteXLSX:0x007fd9cf8aa290>
```

I'm not sure if this is something write_xlsx specific or if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: So... You need to write some logic using the `params` which were supplied by the user? What `params` are you collecting? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: I have never tried `write_xlsx` but based on the fact that you want some portion of a model to export I would highly recommend  [`axlsx`](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) and [`axlsx_rails`](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) which implements a method called `acts_as_axlsx` and it will just take a `ActiveRecord::Relation` (meaning you can use query methods to filter) and output a xlsx from this.

Comment: @TomLord it's not about the filtering itself, I can't even create the file. My step is to simulate a dynamic file but for now the content would be static. I just don't want to create the file on the server, send it to the customer and delete it afterwards

Comment: @engineersmnky I found that one later, prob gonna switch. thx

Answer (score 1):

To save 'export.xlsx' to disk, you should use Workbook#close.
see generate_xlsx method below.

```
def generate_xlsx
  workbook = WriteXLSX.new('export.xlsx')

  worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet

  worksheet.write(0, 0, 'status')
  worksheet.write(0, 1, 'date')
  worksheet.write(0, 2, 'customer')

  workbook.close   # <- Workbook#close
end
```

you can read documents at http://cxn03651.github.io/write_xlsx/index.html.

enjoy!